# how to set traffic statistics in mininet?

Tags: sdn, mininet, pox

I want to make testbed for testing the my own algorithm in mininet. I want to setup link data traffic rate, control traffic rate and link processing rate. but i am not able to it. if anyone have idea how to set up all these. please help me.

thanks,
abha

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has happened? What did you expect to happen? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have made a network which consists of some switches as nodes and links between these nodes and a controller as pox. load balancing balancing application is working. I want to find out  avg. delay of network for which i need to  setup link data traffic rate(40packet/s), control traffic rate(20packet/s) and link processing rate.  how to setup these parmeters

Comment: how to use d-itg to generate continuous random traffic in the network with abilene topology and and each switch has 3  hosts? I want that traffic should look like internet traffic.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** Use **[D-ITG](http://traffic.comics.unina.it/software/ITG/)** to generate traffic of your choice.

To define a topology in Mininet -

You can use the [MininetEdit.py](http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-use-miniedit-mininets-graphical-user-interface/) application in `mininet/examples/miniedit.py` folder. This will create a .py file defining the topology. You could have also written the same code to create the topology, the MininetEdit application is just a GUI to make it easy.

A sample topology definition looks something like this -

(I have created a simple network with 2 hosts `h1, h2` connected to a switch `s1`)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
... #More import calls

def myNetwork(net):

info( '*** Add switches\n')
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')


info( '*** Add hosts\n')
h1 = net.addHost('h1',ip='10.0.0.1',defaultRoute=None)    
h2 = net.addHost('h2',ip='10.0.0.2',defaultRoute=None)

info( '*** Add links\n')    
net.addLink(h1, s1,bw=200,delay='0ms',loss=0,max_queue_size=1000)
net.addLink(h2, s1,bw=200,delay='0ms',loss=0,max_queue_size=1000)
return net
```

You can set the maximum **link rate / bandwitdh** in the MininetEdit app, or change the **bw** parameter in the addLink function in the code file manually.

If you want to generate some real traffic on this mininet topology, use **[D-ITG](http://traffic.comics.unina.it/software/ITG/)**. This is a simple tool that will allow you to generate traffic with different distributions, inter-arrival times, packet sizes, etc.,

So if you want to generate constant rate traffic of say  *rate* KB/s from host `h1` to `h2`, you can follow these steps -

Run `xterm h1` from mininet instance

Run the following command on the terminal of `h1`

```
ITGSend -a <ip_of_h2> -T UDP -C <rate> -c <packet_size>
```

You can refer the D-ITG manual for more.

Comment: Thanks, i ll try it